# udev not updating usb permissions and group

Tags: usb, permissions, udev

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - Lucid Lynx. I have a requirement to set specific group and permissions for any USB stick file/directories on mount. I have tried overwriting the udev rules. Here is what I have done:

1. Created `99-test.rules` under `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory with content as **`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",GROUP="tomcat6",MODE="0777",NAME="test"`**
2. `sudo service udev restart`

Now when I mount the usb stick and run `sudo blkid`, it prints

```
/dev/test: UUID="002A-0AA5" TYPE="vfat"
```

But the `ls -l /media/` gives back

```
drwx------ 4 admin admin 8192 1969-12-31 16:00 002A-0AA5
```

It seems that above rule from `99-test.rules` is getting applied but getting overwritten afterwards, thus changing group and permissions back to some default value. What is it I am missing here? Do I have to change anything else?

Comment: An aside: I gather from the name that you are testing this rule, but before you actually put it in place you might want to add something like  KERNEL=="sd?1" so it does only apply to USB storage devices (and not cameras, audio devices, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `ACTION=="add"` as trigger for that rule.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",KERNEL=="sd?1",GROUP="adm",MODE="0777",SYMLINK+="test"
```

- I don't know why, but ACTION== stopped the rule from working at all.
- The kernel rule was necessary to avoid a conflict between the stick and the stick's partition, I suspect that was the problem you were seeing.
- The symlink is to get rid of an error message about a conflict between the kernel device name and the rule device name. You get a /dev/test that has a symlink to /dev/sdb1, or such.

On 12.04 restarting udev wasn't necessary when testing the rule. Error messages were logged at /var/log/syslog, so I used `tail -f /var/log/syslog` as I mounted the USB drive to watch for them.

You may wish to add more tests so you can limit your rule to just the drive(s) you want /dev/test to map to in case you might plug a camera or other device in simultaneously with you memory stick.